# connect PHP with MS Access 2007-2010 on Linux

Tags: php, linux, ms-access

I have code to connect PHP with Microsoft Access 2007-2010, and I am using a Linux server (Fedora).

My Access db file is in the same folder with index php page
but when I try to load the page all I get is a blank page.

This is my index.php page:

```
<?php
$db = 'test.mdb';
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');

$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db") or exit('Cannot open with driver.');

$sql = 'SELECT   first, second, last FROM t1 ORDER BY id';
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql);

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Quantity Per Unit</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
</tr>
<?php while (!$rs->EOF) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rs->Fields['first']->Value ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rs->Fields['second']->Value ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rs->Fields['last']->Value ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $rs->MoveNext() ?>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<?php

$rs->Close();
$conn->Close();

$rs = null;
$conn = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code on my WAMP test box I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
> **Description:** [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.' in ...

I got it to work by using this instead:

```php
$db = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] . '/../test.mdb';
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');

try {
    $conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db"); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Cannot open with driver: <br/>' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

**However...**

I'm not sure that it will help you if you are executing the code on a Linux box. You are trying to use `COM` (a.k.a. `com_dotnet`), and I'm pretty sure that the COM/.NET extension is only available on Windows servers.

You *might* try using `unixODBC` and `MDB Tools` instead of `COM`, but I wouldn't recommend it myself. If you are going to be running this on a Linux server then I would suggest that you export the database to MySQL or some other database platform with better support for PHP on Linux.

Comment: that not work.thanks for try. same problem blank page.and i am try this code in widows and i get this error Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found

Comment: @user3264926 If you get the "Class not found" error on Windows it means that the COM/.NET extension has not been enabled. Just add or uncomment the line `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` in php.ini.

Comment: i am do it , i am add extension=php_com_dotnet.dll in php.ini, but i get same problem